# AWS EC2 S3 CloudFrontについて

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

現在WordpressをEC2とS3を合併して画像サイトを運営しているのですが、CloudFrontというのを使ったほうが良いのでしょうか？
調べるとCDNはただ単に高速表示させるということなのですが、転送量が多ければ料金が高いということです。

GETリクエスト数 平均ファイルサイズ データ転送量 転送料金 リクエスト料金 合計料金
3千万(100万/日) 100KB 2.8TB $574 .86 $11 .10 $585 .96
Qiita http://qiita.com/kawaz/items/07d67a851fd49c1c183e

WEBサイトを高速に表示させるのは当然大事なことですが、それだけで月額6万円もします。
S3とEC2だけでもさほど遅いとは感じないのですが、どこを調べてもCloudFrontを使ったやり方が書いてあるので、使ったほうが良いかと思いました。

6万円払う価値があるほどの高速になるのでしょうか？

また、GETリクエスト数というのはそのサイトのPVではなく、一枚のファイルのアクセス数ですよね？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFrontの利用はメリットが多いですが、コンテンツをキャッシュしますので、構築されるWebサイトで問題が無いか十分確認された方が良いと思います。キャッシュされると不都合がある場合は、コンテンツ側でキャッシュヘッダを変更するか、CloudFront側で設定変更が必要です。

その上で、CloudFrontはトータルで見るとそんなに高くないです。
コストはサービス単位ではなくAWS利用量全体を比較して考える必要があると思います。

「CloudFront -> S3/EC2など」のトラフィック課金は1,2年前から無料になっています。ですので、2.8TBのデータ転送量に対する課金がCloudFrontに付くか、S3/EC2に付くか変わるだけで全体コストの違いは無いです。（全てのリージョンで確認していませんが、S3/EC2の東京リージョンとCloudFrontの日本では転送料単価も同じです。）

リクエスト課金はキャッシュヒット率で変わります。極端な例でキャッシュヒット率０だとCloudFrontでもS3でも課金されるので、計算された方が良いですが、小規模なサイトだと大きな額にはならないです。

Answer (score 1):

「6万円払う価値があるほどの高速になるのでしょうか？」というのは主観的な質問で貴方にしか分かりません…。

ただ、その計算の価格は変更されてるのでもう少し安いです。
[Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) で計算したら $419.67 でした。(東京リージョン)

また、「転送量が多ければ料金が高い」というのは CloudFront に限らず S3 / EC2 どちらも 転送量に対して料金が発生します。

仮に CloudFrontを使わず全て S3 からの インターネットへの送信するという場合、2.8TB、GETリクエストが3千万 で計算すると $410.40 でしたので CloudFrontが特別高い印象はありません。

ただ、独自ドメインでSSLを使う場合は注意が必要です。専用IP独自SSLは $600/月 なので割高感があります。SNI独自SSLであれば別途料金はかかりませんが古いブラウザは対応していないようでアクセスできなくなります。

あとは[CDP](http://aws.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA:CDP:%E9%9D%99%E7%9A%84%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%84%E3%82%92%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3) などを参考にしてCloudFrontに魅力を感じれば使えば良いのではと思います。